# Track navigation after opening an org link

Tags: org-mode, org-link

This is a longshot, but does the following exist already?

- You have an link in your org file like:

  ```
  * TODO Learn elisp
  [[info:eintr#Arguments][eintr#Arguments]]
  ```
- You open that link.
- You go to the next page in the linked-to-document
- Then the requested functionality:

  - The link in the org file is updated with the new location automatically
  - OR, you invoke a command which updates the link in the org file.

This saves so much hassle to keep your progress up-to-date without having to retrace your steps if you forgot to update the link and continuing after a long time period.

Comment: You could probably implement such a mechanism, but I think you are really looking for [bookmarks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bookmarks.html). There is more information about the enhanced `bookmarks+` package on [Emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).

Comment: The Emacs tutorial (`M-x help-with-tutorial`) already offers to save your position. You could also look up how the Emacs tutorial saves/restores position in `tutorial--save-tutorial` and `help-with-tutorial` (i.e. I think it's an easier mechanism than updating the link in the org file). Then you can just link to `eintr`, and let the mechanism do its work.